# Domain + AWS EC2: How to make www.mydomain.com point to my EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a website and I just bought a domain at domain.com. I also launched an EC2 instance in AWS. Which one of the options would I choose below so that going to www.edmundscoolsite.com would point to my EC2 instance?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a couple of options here.

The best option is to associate an [elastic IP address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) with your EC2 instance, then use an A record. The EIP is yours until you release it, even if you replace your instance.

An alternative option is to make `www.edmundscoolsite.com` a `CNAME` record whose value is the public DNS for your EC2 instance, something like `ec2-1-2-3-4.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`. When you replace your EC2 instance the CNAME will no longer be valid, however, which is why the first option is better.

Answer (score 1):

In order to point www.edmundscoolsite.com  to your EC2 instance, you can add a CNAME or A record.

more here : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=87279